# weird method applyForceToCenter in box2d

Tags: box2d

I have just learned to use box2d. Here is my problem.

When the system starts, if I use the method `ApplyForceToCenter` to control the box's speed, the body just flies away, but the next time I involve `ApplyForceToCenter` method, it returns to normal, the box does not fly, its speed is right.

What I mean is the method `ApplyForceToCenter`, the first time is wrong, the next and other times are right.

Can someone help me out? I really appreciate it.

BTW, I am not using it in world's `Step()`, I just involve it in my Class Method.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be My Schedule run a little bit slow which makes World's Step accept a timeStep bigger than expected. then use F* t(bigger) = m * vt - m * v0 the vt is very bigger. the result is the box flying away.